# Disable clickable image but enable right click context menu

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, image

[image]

*Example image from reddit.com*

Picture sums up what I want to do with CSS (and JS if needed)

Essentially:

- I want to have an image on some website to be left-unclickable to its imageURL
- I want the ability to have a right-clickable context menu so I can open that imageURL in a new tab if needed

**How would I do this purely with CSS (am using chrome stylish plugin) and if needed Javascript?**

Currently I was using this:

`pointer-events: none;` on the CSS class

but this disables the ability to have a right-click context menu

Comment: I'm curious what the bigger picture problem you're trying to solve is.

Comment: `onclick="return false;"` (or some other method to do the same such as jquery click event handler return false)  https://jsfiddle.net/65bztLnp/

Comment: mkaatman its for my dynalist.io notes. This thread was  the original issue I had http://talk.dynalist.io/t/option-to-prevent-markdown-images-from-being-clickable/888/2

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure if you could do this with CSS only. To accomplish this with JS, try the following code:

```
<a href="#link" onclick="event.preventDefault();">
    <img src="img.jpg"/>
</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this: `<IMG border=0 src="..." oncontextmenu="return false;">`

Demo here: http://www.javascripter.net/faq/rightbu2.htm